# Trouble playing vid pre-roll ad in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript, vast

I'm trying to add VAST video pre-roll ads to the [SThree sample Roku SDK project](https://blog.roku.com/developer/2016/03/03/scenegraph-tutorial/) (the "Simple Grid with Video and Details page (.zip)" version).

I can get it to work on app start by putting the following code into `main.brs`:

```
library "Roku_Ads.brs"
...
Sub RunUserInterface()
    ...
    raf = Roku_Ads() 
    raf.setAdPrefs(false)       'disable back-filled ads
    raf.setDebugOutput(true)
    raf.setAdUrl("http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?slotname=/82114269/Video/fallbacktest&sz=1920x1080&url=[http://roku.com&unviewed_position_start=1&output=vast&impl=s&env=vp&gdfp_req=1&ad_rule=0&description_url=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.roku.com&vad_type=linear&sdkv=roku&min_ad_duration=0&max_ad_duration=60000&rdid=ROKU_ADS_TRACKING_ID&is_lat=ROKU_ADS_LIMIT_TRACKING&idtype=rida&correlator=ROKU_ADS_TIMESTAMP&scor=ROKU_ADS_TIMESTAMP&pod=POD_NUM&ppos=POD_POSITION&cust_params=genre%3DROKU_ADS_CONTENT_GENRE%26ua%3DROKU_ADS_USER_AGENT%26ai%3DROKU_ADS_APP_ID]http://roku.com&unviewed_position_start=1&output=vast&impl=s&env=vp&gdfp_req=1&ad_rule=0&description_url=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.roku.com&vad_type=linear&sdkv=roku&min_ad_duration=0&max_ad_duration=60000&rdid=ROKU_ADS_TRACKING_ID&is_lat=ROKU_ADS_LIMIT_TRACKING&idtype=rida&correlator=ROKU_ADS_TIMESTAMP&scor=ROKU_ADS_TIMESTAMP&pod=POD_NUM&ppos=POD_POSITION&cust_params=genre%3DROKU_ADS_CONTENT_GENRE%26ua%3DROKU_ADS_USER_AGENT%26ai%3DROKU_ADS_APP_ID") 
    adPods = raf.getAds()
    shouldPlayContent = raf.showAds(adPods)
```

I however don't want to play an ad on startup, I want to play an ad before a video play.  So I figure I can just add the lines above to `components/screens/DetailsScreen/DetailsScreen.brs`:

```
' on Button press handler
Sub onItemSelected()
    ' first button is Play
    if m.top.itemSelected = 0
        'START ADDING FOR PRE-ROLL
        raf = Roku_Ads() 
        raf.setAdPrefs(false)       'disable back-filled ads
        raf.setDebugOutput(true)
        raf.setAdUrl("http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?slotname=/82114269/Video/fallbacktest&sz=1920x1080&url=[http://roku.com&unviewed_position_start=1&output=vast&impl=s&env=vp&gdfp_req=1&ad_rule=0&description_url=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.roku.com&vad_type=linear&sdkv=roku&min_ad_duration=0&max_ad_duration=60000&rdid=ROKU_ADS_TRACKING_ID&is_lat=ROKU_ADS_LIMIT_TRACKING&idtype=rida&correlator=ROKU_ADS_TIMESTAMP&scor=ROKU_ADS_TIMESTAMP&pod=POD_NUM&ppos=POD_POSITION&cust_params=genre%3DROKU_ADS_CONTENT_GENRE%26ua%3DROKU_ADS_USER_AGENT%26ai%3DROKU_ADS_APP_ID]http://roku.com&unviewed_position_start=1&output=vast&impl=s&env=vp&gdfp_req=1&ad_rule=0&description_url=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.roku.com&vad_type=linear&sdkv=roku&min_ad_duration=0&max_ad_duration=60000&rdid=ROKU_ADS_TRACKING_ID&is_lat=ROKU_ADS_LIMIT_TRACKING&idtype=rida&correlator=ROKU_ADS_TIMESTAMP&scor=ROKU_ADS_TIMESTAMP&pod=POD_NUM&ppos=POD_POSITION&cust_params=genre%3DROKU_ADS_CONTENT_GENRE%26ua%3DROKU_ADS_USER_AGENT%26ai%3DROKU_ADS_APP_ID") 
        adPods = raf.getAds()
        shouldPlayContent = raf.showAds(adPods)
        'END ADDING FOR PRE-ROLL

        if shouldPlayContent
            m.videoPlayer.visible = true
            m.videoPlayer.setFocus(true)
            m.videoPlayer.control = "play"
            m.videoPlayer.observeField("state", "OnVideoPlayerStateChange")
        end if
    end if
End Sub
```

When I run this I get an error:

```
Roku_Ads Framework version 1.8
BRIGHTSCRIPT: ERROR: roAppInfo: class PLUGIN|MARKUP on thread RENDER: roku_ads_lib:/Roku_Ads.brs(527)
'Dot' Operator attempted with invalid BrightScript Component or interface reference. (runtime error &hec) in roku_ads_lib:/Roku_Ads.brs(528)
528: ??
Backtrace:
#4  Function roku_ads_util_getappid(key_ As String) As String
   file/line: roku_ads_lib:/Roku_Ads.brs(528)
#3  Function roku_ads_checkallowedfeature(keytype_ As String, util_ As Object) As Boolean
   file/line: roku_ads_lib:/Roku_Ads.brs(1287)
#2  Function roku_ads_constructor() As Object
   file/line: roku_ads_lib:/Roku_Ads.brs(264)
#1  Function roku_ads() As Object
   file/line: roku_ads_lib:/Roku_Ads.brs(32)
#0  Function onitemselected() As Void
   file/line: pkg:/components/screens/DetailsScreen/DetailsScreen.brs(75)
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Can you not play an ad when a method is called from a `onChange="onItemSelected"` in the component.xml?

**Update**: Eugene's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40546789/563420) is correct, Here is how I solved the problem:

Read about [scene graph threads](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Scene+Graph+Threads), [events](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Event+Loops) and [handling application events](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Handling+Application+Events).  Once that is done read [this post](https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=92613&p=543771#p543771) on passing data between the Render thread and main thread.  You will need to understand [scene graph data scoping](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Scene+Graph+Data+Scoping).

Essentially you observe the `itemSelected` field in `components/screens/DetailsScreen/DetailsScreen.xml`:

```
m.DetailsScreen = scene.findNode("DetailsScreen")
m.DetailsScreen.observeField("itemSelected", m.port)
```

Then in your main threads event loop you handle the `roSGNodeEvent`:

```
while true
    msg = wait(0, m.port)        
    msgType = type(msg)

    ? ">>>Main Thread Msg: ";msgType

    if msgType = "roSGScreenEvent"
        if msg.isScreenClosed() then return
    else if msgType = "roSGNodeEvent"
        fieldName = msg.getField()
        fieldData = msg.getData()
        ? "> node: "; msg.getNode()
        ? "> field name: "; fieldName
        ? "> data: "; fieldData

        if (fieldName = "itemSelected" and fieldData = 0)   'User pressed play
            'wait for 0.5 second before proceeding to RAF
            sleep(500)
            PlayAd()
        endif
    end if
end while
```

`PlayAd()` sets `m.DetailsScreen.videoPlayerVisible = true` IF there was no ad or if ad finished playing.  This causes `onVideoVisibleChange` to be invoked in `components/screens/DetailsScreen/DetailsScreen.brs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use RAF in Render thread. You have to send event to the Main thread and and show ads there. You can find samples of RAF integration in Scene Graph [here](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Roku+Advertising+Framework). More info on threads in Scene Graph can be found [here](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Scene+Graph+Threads).

Comment: Thanks @eugene-smoliy, that makes sense and so does the high level docs on threads you linked to.  Where can I find the docs about message passing? From looking at the FullRAFSceneGraphSample it looks like main thread waits on them in the event loop. I can prob fig out via trial and error but would rather read docs about topic - which I'm having trouble finding...

Comment: I found it, https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Handling+Application+Events I'll update this SO with what needs to be added to the SThree sample to get ads to play once I get it working