# RAF SDK not working in SceneGraph application (BrightScript)

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am creating my own channel for Roku. I need to get the streams of my videos and ads pod. Code wrote in .xml or task node file -

```
   adIface = Roku_Ads()
   adIface.setAdUrl(adUrl)
   adPods = adIface.getAds()
   shouldPlayContent = adIface.showAds(adPods)
```

This code working fine in main.brs file but in .xml file or task node generate error- " **'Dot' Operator attempted with invalid BrightScript Component or interface reference. (runtime error
&hec) in roku_ads_lib:/Roku_Ads.brs(2762)
2762: ??**" . Please give me solution.

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538096/trouble-playing-vid-pre-roll-ad-in-roku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lacking important info from the error message - specifically the stack trace that was going to show which line of your code that happens (i.e. not only the library line#)

But let me guess - you haven't set anything in `adUrl`, so invoking `adIface.setAdUrl()` with a null reference? Just comment out that line to use the default ad URL, add later if needed.

Comment: you cannot use RAF in the render thread. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40546789/226086